# Display edit link if post author is current user

Tags: users, author

I am creating an author.php page and listing all the posts from an author. Although admins can see the posts' edit links i want to echo the link if logged in user is the current user

for example

if testuser is logged in and current page is /author/testuser he can see edit post links

but

if testuser is logged in and current page is /author/theee he cant see the links

currently i have

```
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
$th = $curauth->nickname; 
$cu = $current_user->user_login;
if ( $th = $curauth ) {
  edit_post_link('edit', '', ''); 
} else {

}
```

but still only admins can see the links.

Comment: Sorry, but the "logged in" user is always going to be the "current user". That is confusing. The Codex reads (emphasis mine): ["Displays a link to edit the current post, **if a user is logged in and allowed to edit the post**."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) That implies that your users can't edit the posts in question, or that they aren't logged in. (And if they aren't logged in WordPress has no way to know if they can edit the post or not.)

Comment: i am trying to say when logged in user views one of the other peoples' author page they shouldn't see edit link but when they view their own author page they should.

Comment: oh... I wouldn't have worked that out. Edit your question please. I've got a solution for you if no one beats me to it.

Comment: In WordPress's [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) model, Editors can edit the posts of other users, whereas Authors can only edit their own.  Could you just make the users in question Authors, and then just use `edit_post_link()`?  Then everything works as expected, for all users, at any level (Author, Editor, Administrator, etc).

Comment: I actually realised that (as you can see on one of my comment below) and it works now :) thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you just have to modify the author.php page, this piece of code will probably work :

```
<?php 

if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) ) {

    edit_post_link('edit', '', '');

}

?>
```

The first part of the conditions checks if there is a user logged.
The second one will be true if the current page is the author page of the current user.

Answer (score 4):

I think the post edit link should be visible to post author and moderator(editor user or how have that capability)

So my proposed code is like this

```
global $post;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts', $post->ID ) && ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID))  { 

    //show edit link    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Placed in your theme's `functions.php` this should globally alter the behavior of [`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link). It should work on all of your archives, not just your author archives-- anything that uses [`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link).

```
function limit_edit_Link_wpse_85214($link) {
  global $post,$current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
    return $link;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter('get_edit_post_link','limit_edit_Link_wpse_85214');
```

If will only work reliably inside a Loop, which is the only place you should be using [`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) anyway.

If you want this to work only for your author archive pages, just paste that code before the Loop in the `author.php` template and don't put it in `function.php`. It shouldn't effect anything but that page then. Or you can just use the guts for the function to make your conditional, like you were trying to do.

Comment: i tried to put put on function page but it didnt work properly. but when i put same code in author.php page as its being in a loop on second field i am having error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare limit_edit_Link_wpse_85214() (previously declared .. i think i need to edit that function code slightly but couldnt do it. how can i edit it sir ?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comparing-the-post-author-id-and-logged-in-user-id i found this helpfull but it seems edit_post_link doesnt work with this code. it echos the text but not link
edit: oh ok. users should be at least and author. silly mistakes :) thanks

Comment: Well, you can't redeclare a function. That is basic PHP. If you copied this to two different files you will have trouble. That code will show the "Edit" link if the current user is the post author, which means that only the author can see the link on an author archive, plus it works on any other archive as well. I tested that when I wrote it, and I tested it again just now. Under what conditions does this not work?

Comment: i used the code from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comparing-the-post-author-id-and-logged-in-user-id . probably my first and your code might even be correct because my problem with user role (changed to author from subscriber).  currently i am trying to let them edit their post on front end as explanied here :http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/posting-via-the-front-end-editing-and-deleting/ but having some issues ..

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the @Mat solution to work. It looks correct, however.

WP stores the value of $post->post_author as a string.  However, `get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )` and `get_current_user_id()` each return an integer, so strict comparison works in the second part of the IF statement.

If you replace `get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )` with `$post->post_author` you must use `==` and not `===` as the comparison operator because the value of $post->post_author is a string and `get_current_user_id()` returns an integer.

Test:

```
<?php echo 'Author ID type: ' . gettype( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . '<br>'; ?>
<?php echo 'Current user ID type: ' . gettype( get_current_user_id() ); ?>
<?php 
    echo 'Is logged in user the author? '; 
    if ( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) == get_current_user_id() ) {
         echo 'TRUE  <br>'; 
    } else {
        echo 'FALSE'; 
    }
?>
```

Solution using strict comparison operator that works for me:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) === get_current_user_id() ) : ?> 

  //...

<?php endif; ?>
```